# Finding nested element using Xpath in Selenium not working

Tags: html, css, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

given the following site and locators:

https://ultimateqa.com/automation

**XPATH**

```
CONTAINER = (By.XPATH, '//ul[@class="bottom-nav"]')
MENU = (By.XPATH, '//li[contains(@class, "menu-item")]')
```

---

**CSS**

```
BOTTOM_NAV = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.bottom-nav')
MENU_ITEM = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.menu-item')
```

I need to find inside the BOTTOM_NAV the number of MENU_ITEMS.

When using nested CSS it is working correctly and returns expected number of menu items which is 7: **parent_css_element.find_elements(css_element)**

When trying the same but with XPATH locators then it is not working and elements inside the parent element are a lot more 21 and more: **parent_xpath_element.find_elements(xpath_element)**

I am trying to figure out why searching in nested element is not working with xpath locators but working correctly with css selectors?

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://ultimateqa.com/automation")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
# Below line can be used to close the subscribe pop-up which appears intermittently
# wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='formkit-close']"))).click()

# Store parent element
parent_element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//ul[@class="bottom-nav"]')))

# Store all the li elements within parent element
count = parent_element.find_elements(By.XPATH, "li")

# print count of li elements
print(len(count))
```

**Console Result:**

```
7

Process finished with exit code 0
```